Jackson Databind Conflicts in Apache Spark Project Using Maven Shade Plugin
I am working on a project that processes IMDb data using Apache Spark. My setup involves Spark Core and Spark SQL dependencies, along with Jackson for handling JSON serialization and deserialization. I’m using Maven to manage dependencies and the Maven Shade Plugin to package my application into a fat JAR for deployment.
The Problem: 
When I run my Spark application, I encounter runtime issues with Jackson, specifically jackson-databind. It appears that there are conflicts between Jackson versions included in the dependencies. Despite specifying the version explicitly in the pom.xml, the issue persists.
Environment 
Java Version: 11 
Spark Version: 3.5.1 
Scala Version: 2.13 
Jackson Version: 2.15.2 
Build Tool: Maven
Error Log stderr in EMR Cluster 
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile(SparkContext.scala:1055)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.textFile(JavaSparkContext.scala:175)
    at org.example.Main.totalTvSeries(Main.java:73)
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:241)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Scala module 2.15.2 requires Jackson Databind version >= 2.15.0 and < 2.16.0 - Found jackson-databind version 2.12.7-1
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:61)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule.setupModule$(JacksonModule.scala:46)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:17)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:835)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
    ... 11 more

My pom.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>IMDBSpark</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spark Core dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spark SQL dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson Databind dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson Scala Module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Align all Jackson dependencies to version 2.15.2 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Shade plugin to create a fat JAR -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>org.example.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


What I tried 
1. Aligning Jackson Versions: I used the dependencyManagement section in Maven to align all Jackson dependencies (jackson-databind, jackson-core, jackson-annotations) to version 2.15.2.
2. Checking for Transitive Dependency Conflicts: I ran mvn dependency:tree and found that some transitive dependencies from Spark include older versions of Jackson. I used <exclusion> in some dependency to remove the jackson-databind.
What I Need Help With: 
How do I resolve this conflict between Jackson and Spark dependencies in a Maven-based project?

You should not use different versions of jars than the Spark runtime you are running on, Spark's class path handling is effectively flat.  If you really want different versions then you must actually shade them.
However from the 3.5.1 tag) it actually should be 2.15.2 that is used.
This seems to indicate that you either have another dependency that is not shown above or the runtime has older jars.  Using your actual pom from the question has the correct versions aligned with spark for example.

I suspect that this may be more a classpath related issue on the EMR Cluster, than a Maven one, if you already checked that your artifact has any of that old dependencies.
Please check these other issues:
Spark EMR job jackson error - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError - AnnotatedMember.getType()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType
How do I set my EMR Classpath
Also in those case, there was a conflict on a Jackson library that was provided in the cluster.

I checked the Jackson Databind version that comes with Spark 3.5.1, and it’s 2.15.x. I used <dependencyManagement> to force my project to use version 2.15.x. But I’m still getting an error saying it found the old version (2.12.x).
When I looked at the dependency tree, it shows my project is using 2.15.2. But on EMR, it seems like the old version is still being used, and I don’t know why.

As I said before, i think that the issue is not in the maven assembly phase, but at runtime: in the EMR image you are using there is a CLASSPATH set that if uses an older version of the databind library. Please chech also this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536553/how-do-i-set-my-emr-classpath to try to solve this.
